# How to sort RecyclerView elements with different types?

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with sorting `RecyclerView` items with different types. For example i have such `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
public class StudyRVadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

private List<Item> data;

public RVadapter(List<Item> src){
    data = src;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;

    switch (viewType){
        case 0:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_0, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolderZero(view);
            break;

        case 1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_1, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolderOne(view);
            break;

        default: vh=null;
    }
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (Item0.class.isInstance(data.get(position))){
        Item0 item0 = (Item0)data.get(position);
        ((ViewHolderZero)holder).text.setText(item0.toStringText());
         }
    if (Item1.class.isInstance(data.get(position))){
        Item1 item1 = (Item1)data.get(position);
       ((ViewHolderOne)holder).text.setText(item1.toStringText());
    }      
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Item item = data.get(position);
    if (Item0.class.isInstance(item)) return 0;
    if (Item1.class.isInstance(item)) return 1;
    throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown element");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class ViewHolderZero extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView text;

    public ViewHolderZero(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem0);

    }
}

public class ViewHolderOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     TextView text2;

    public ViewHolderOne(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem1);
    }
}
```

In my main `Activity` i create `LinkedList` and add elements with types "Item0" and "Item1":

```
LinkedList<Item> ll = new LinkedList<>();
ll.add(0, new Item0("abc"));
ll.add(1, new Item1("bca"));
```

i tried to use `Comparator`:

```
class Comparation implements Comparator<Item> {

    public int compare(Item0 lhs, Item1 rhs) {

        if (lhs.getText() < rhs.getText()){
            return 1;
        }else return -1;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work because of wrong args in `compare()`.

If i understand correctly, i can use `Collections.sort()` and `Comparator` for list, wich consists of same-type elements. But how can i sort different-type elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `Item0` and `Item1` subclasses of `Item` (if they are not already).

`getText()` should be a method of `Item` (which `Item1` and `Item2` will inherit).

After that, you can compare them properly, since they are of the same type:

```
class Comparation implements Comparator<Item> {

    public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
        // your comparation logic
    }
}
```

Comment: As a bonus: if `getText()` returns a String (or has a `toString()`) method, you could also just do: `return lhs.getText().compareTo(rhs.getText())`